# How to write javascript for validation for not allowing special characters?

Tags: javascript

I have textbox in which I have to restrict only alphabates and special characters except $#%^@? = +~ these special characters

I am using JavaScript for validation

I used following code for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                     
            var frmvalidator = new Validator("ExporterEditContactPersonForm");
            frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
            frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

            frmvalidator.addValidation("landMark", "regexp=^[\\S]",
                    "Landmark should not start with space");
            frmvalidator.addValidation("landMark", "regexp=^[A-Za-z0-9]",
                    "Landmark should not start with special character");
</script>
```

so now I am not getting how to achieve above said condition.

Comment: What is "special characters"?

Comment: exactly. When you are not using so many what are you refering to as?
Do you mean space and  _???

Comment: sorry i didn't get your question?

Comment: actually m working on a project and this was mentioned in the FRS

Comment: field should be allowed all special characters except $#%^@? = +~

Comment: this is the condition written in FRS

Comment: is it only alphbets or is it alphanumeric?

Comment: exactly.. smoeone please give me right solution. Because i have more defects related to this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your query includes only alphabets and excluding "$#%^@? = +~ –". However in your comments you have mentioned alphanumeric so the solution is for alphanumeric

Secondly i hope you have included javascript validation script
http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">                     
            var frmvalidator = new Validator("ExporterEditContactPersonForm");
            frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
            frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

            frmvalidator.addValidation("landMark", "regexp=^\S",
                    "Landmark should not start with space");  //\s matched white space and \S matched non white space so you need to check if it not white space
            frmvalidator.addValidation("landMark", "regexp=^[a-zA-Z0-9]",
                    "Landmark should not start with special character");
```

frmvalidator.addValidation("landMark", "regexp=^(?:\w|[^$#%^@? = +~ –])+$",
                        "Landmark should contain only   alphanumeric and should not contain few special characters"); //for your question that ur textbox should contain only alphanumeric and except those special character  you need to do this equivalent in your form validator

```
</script>
```

note:
 "Landmark should contain only   alphanumeric and should not contain few special characters"//for your question that ur textbox should contain only alphanumeric and except those special character  you need to do this equivalent in your form validator

```
var myRe = /[$#%^@? = +~ –]+/gmi;
if(myRe.test("adssad232++"))
{
console.log('this string is invalid since it contains the restricted special characters');
}
```

I am sorry i got confused with validator about when the error msg is shown, is it if returned true or false. Changed second validator back

Comment: sorry i had made it * instead of +. Updated my answer

Comment: i tested the latest update and everything is working